# Why am I getting NoClassDefFoundError / ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, cmd

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) accordingly.

Up to running the FirstExample class in the command prompt is when it starts to freak out for some reason. After attempting to run the following command:

```
java FirstExample
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FirstExample
```

I understand that it can't find the FirstExample class due to the classpath (for some reason) so I executed the following command:

```
java -cp . FirstExample
```

And now it returns a new exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Now it can't find the JDBC Driver. This confuses me because for starters, I ran the exact same coding through Eclipse and it works as expected, and secondly, I went as far as to ensure that I execute the same class file that Eclipse is executing, and the command prompt still returns exceptions. I also went as far as to put the FirstExample file in a separate folder, just for the purpose of copying and pasting the MySQL Connector into the same folder, and I still get exceptions.

I just don't understand whats going on, can someone help me please?

Many thanks.

---

The file path to the connector is as followed:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar
```

Hope this helps.

---

For testing purposes, I have placed the FirstExample class under the following path:

```
C:\java
```

Comment: Do u have jar file something like ojdbc14.jar in your classpath? if not for a testing purpose you can put this jar at the same location where your class file is and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This confuses me because for starters, I ran the exact same coding through Eclipse and it works as expected

This is because in Eclipse you add the libraries to the Build Path, and it will use all the libraries specified there in the classpath automatically when running your project. This can be noted here:

[image: Eclipse Build Path]

In order for you to execute your project using third party libraries from command line tools, you should specify the libraries manually in your classpath explicitly:

```
java -cp <path/to/mysql_jar/goes/here>:. FirstExample
```

---

By your comment:

> the path to the MySQL file is: C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar (...) I have placed the FirstExample class under C:\java

This should be the command line to use:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar; ." FirstExample
```

Note that it is better to store all the third party libraries in a single folder within your project, usually called lib, and put a reference to there. Assuming your current folder has a lib folder and all the third party libraries are copied there, the command line would be:

```
java -cp "lib\*; ." FirstExample
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply; the path to the MySQL file is: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar`. I've tried this command with no success, however I might be inputting it incorrectly. Can you clarify how I would go about specifying the library in the command prompt? Many thanks.

Comment: Also for testing purposes, I have placed the FirstExample class under `C:\java`.

Comment: Based on your answer, has it always worked like this? Because if so, you would think that the tutorial would specify this. xp

Comment: Yes, and it is covered in the tutorials.

Comment: It does? I must of missed it, where is it exactly? It does mention about setting the Environment Variables under JDBC - Environments, but I don't see any mention of `-cp` or `"lib\*; ."`.

Comment: @KurtissBolam check here: [java command line options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (and all the imported classes) in the classpath too.

You should download the jar (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) and add it to the classpath.

Comment: You want to imply that just putting the jar in the same directory puts it on the classpath?

Comment: No, that wasn't what I wanted to say... but that's what I said. I'm going to edit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; and yes, I have already downloaded Connector/J as it was described under the tutorial as this problem persists. Again, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use the next example to add your jars to the classpath:

```
java -cp "jdbc.jar;lib/*" my.package.FirstExample
```

Answer (score 0):

The ClassNotFound Exception rises when there is an issue with the class name that you have written in Class.forName() or if the package is not set to the classpath variable. Make sure that you have added the jar file to the classpath ( C:............\jarfilename.jar;). 
   This is applicable for any JDBC Driver and jar files. The .jar files that are added to the classpath will not be visible to IDEs, in this case, you need to add the jar files to buildpath (in eclipse) or you can also copy the jar files to ext folder available in the Java installation folder.

Also note that the jar files of the DB Softwares may vary based on the DB software version that you are using for example if you are using the Oracle 11g, you need ojdbc6.jar file, in other versions of Oracle the number changes like ojdbc14.jar etc.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have checked the CLASSPATH under the system's environment variables settings and it is as followed: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar`. Again, thank you for your reply.